# Which is a programm a free and modern for video effects and video editing?

Tags: video, video-editing

The **programm** must to be published or upgrated in **2019** year. It isn't a capture software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like [lightworks](https://www.lwks.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=162&Itemid=246&start=QuickStart)
With [free](https://www.lwks.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=102&Itemid=213) version for for Windows, Mac and Linux.

Also take a lot to [shotcut](https://shotcut.org/blog/new-release-190430/) free and multiplatform.

Answer (score 0):

[OpenShot](https://www.openshot.org/) is an easy to use, quick to learn, and surprisingly powerful video editor. OpenShot is a free, open-source video editor for Windows, Mac and Linux.

#### Features

- Support for many video, audio, and image formats
- Powerful curve-based Key frame animations
- Desktop integration (drag and drop support)
- Unlimited tracks / layers
- Clip resizing, scaling, trimming, snapping, rotation, and cutting
- Video transitions with real-time previews
- Compositing, image overlays, watermarks
- Title templates, title creation, subtitles
- 3D animated titles (and effects)
- Advanced Timeline (including drag and drop, scrolling, panning, zooming, and snapping)
- Frame accuracy (step through each frame of video)
- Time-mapping and speed changes on clips (slow/fast, forward/backward, etc...)
- Audio mixing and editing
- Digital **video effects**, including brightness, gamma, hue, grayscale, chroma key (bluescreen / greenscreen), and many more..

[OpenShot User Guide](https://www.openshot.org/static/files/user-guide/index.html)